# why entire mysql resultset using node js coming up in array format?

Tags: json, node.js

using the following node js script i get the entire mysql result set in array format. How it can be removed?

```
var pricingDetail = function(resourceIdentifiers,callback){
    dbconnection.execute(function(err,response){

    if(err){
        throw err;
        }
    else 
        { 

            var selectqueryString = "call SP_ExposePricingDetailforUI('" + resourceIdentifiers + "')";
            response.query(selectqueryString, function(err, result){
            if(err) {   
                throw err;          
            }
            else 
            {
                callback(result);

            }
            });
        }

});
};
```

Result :

```
[
  {
    "ResourceIdentifier": "vm/hpcloud/nova/small",
    "chargeAmount": 0.071,
    "ChargeAmountUnit": "per hour",
    "CurrencyCode": "USD"
  },
  {
    "ResourceIdentifier": "vm/hpcloud/nova/large",
    "chargeAmount": 0.49,
    "ChargeAmountUnit": "per hour",
    "CurrencyCode": "USD"
  },
  {
    "ResourceIdentifier": "vm/hpcloud/nova/large",
    "chargeAmount": 0.49,
    "ChargeAmountUnit": "per hour",
    "CurrencyCode": "USD"
  },
  {
    "ResourceIdentifier": "vm/hpcloud/nova/large",
    "chargeAmount": 0.8,
    "ChargeAmountUnit": "per hour",
    "CurrencyCode": "USD"
  },
  {
    "ResourceIdentifier": "vm/hpcloud/nova/large",
    "chargeAmount": 0.8,
    "ChargeAmountUnit": "per hour",
    "CurrencyCode": "USD"
  },
  {
    "ResourceIdentifier": "vm/hpcloud/nova/large",
    "chargeAmount": 0.78,
    "ChargeAmountUnit": "per hour",
    "CurrencyCode": "USD"
  },
  {
    "ResourceIdentifier": "vm/hpcloud/nova/large",
    "chargeAmount": 0.78,
    "ChargeAmountUnit": "per hour",
    "CurrencyCode": "USD"
  }
]
```

Comment: What do you expect the result to be?

Comment: How what can be removed?  Is it the entire array, a specific result in the array, or perhaps this question from stack overflow?